# JAX-WS RS with Apache CXF - GZIP Compression

Tags: java, rest, jax-ws, cxf, gzip

I'm creating a RESTFul WS using JAX-RS with Apache CXF. I want to be able to compress the data being returned. An example of my code is:

```
 @POST  
 @Path("testGZIPMethod")
 @GZIP
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  
 public String testGZIPMethod(@FormParam("userinput")String userinput)  
 {
     //return JSON String
 }
```

When i try to compile my class using JDev, i get the following error: annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration. The annotation causing this error is @GZIP. Any idea where to move on from here?

Comment: No Stacktrace at all. Simply the sentence: "Error(2953,6):  annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration"

Comment: Try to add @GZIP to the class instead of the method

Answer (score 1):

The @GZIP annotation can only be applied to types and not to methods:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
public @interface GZIP {
    int threshold() default -1;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate further please? Do you mean the annotation should be at the level of the class and not the method?

Comment: yes. @GZIP is defined with target "TYPE". it can't be used to annotate a "METHOD"